# How to prove dependency of a family member on EU citizen?

Tags: eu, eu-citizens, family, europe

I'm a German citizen living & working in Austria. My parents are non-eu. I want to practice my right and invite them to live with me in Austria according to the Freedom of Movement Act/EU. However once of the main requirement is that I need to prove that my parents are dependent on me. I read that one sufficient proof is regular (monthly) transfers to them. However there is one big problem:

Their home country (where they currently live as well) has no access to the international banking system due to international sanctions. So not a single bank or any money transfer system is allowed to send them money (i.e yes even Western Union doesn't send money there).

Because of this ban, I was always sending them money via friends. However, because this has always been done via friends who were traveling to their country, then I have no documents to prove that I was sending them money regularly.

So can someone tell me what other ways which are accepted which I can use to prove their dependency on me?

Comment: One option might be to get a pre-pay debit card account that you can transfer money to and they can use in ATMs and stores where they live. The account will be in your name but typically you can request a secondary card(s) in the name of your parents, statement transactions would show a deposit from you and withdrawals in their home town, which might be enough to convince Austrian immigration

Comment: @Traveller doesn't a prepaid debit card imply access to the international banking system?

Comment: @phoog You’re right, it may not work. But it does for me and my partner, to whom I can’t even send £stg through a UK bank thanks to US sanctions. So I thought it was worth putting the option on the table. If the country where the OP’s parents live has no ATMs that accept foreign-issued cards, then it won’t work.